Oracle Apex 22.2 Page items view shows no rows, Session state shows the page items
I am having problem where Oracle Apex Session state is not showing page items. When I open session state and page items view is empty (We are using APEX 22.2 version). See picture below:

But when under view you choose Session State and click Set button it is showing Page items with their values. See picture below:

Does anybody have any clue why is this happening?
Thanks a lot.

Any chance the page 106 items are set to maintain session state "per user"?

@GregJarm no, they are set to Per session, https://imgur.com/74aoI4E
